# Regex with more than one OR/AND operator

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match text that is:

- a combination of numbers and letters, and might contain [`:,.`]

OR

- a `*` character plus at least one number OR letter (not necessarily in this order)

Meaning my regex should match all these

```
Bf1305020008401 6798ubbii230693
Nettbank til: Troij iudh Betalt: 03.05.13
7509*30.04
*87589
```

but not these:

```
&nbsp;
0205
252,25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [regex alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with `|` does not have the meaning in a character group (e.g. `[a-z|0-9]`) that it does elsewhere in a pattern.  (Think of it as implied between characters & character ranges within a character group, making it redundant.)

## Pattern

This pattern should do what you need:

```
^((?=^.{0,}[0-9])(?=^.{0,}[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z :,.]{2,}|(?!^\*$)(?=^[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,})(?!^[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*)[*0-9.a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

It matches...

```
Bf1305020008401 6798ubbii230693
Nettbank til: Troij iudh Betalt: 03.05.13
7509*30.04
*87589
```

...and does not match...

```
&nbsp;
0205
252,25
```

...as you require.

You can try the pattern with the inputs you specified in a [regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/fpx3j).

## Explanation

Some explanation for the 1st subpattern (on the left side of the `|`) matching your 1st set of match criteria:

1. `(?=^.{0,}[0-9])` - Assert that a number appears in the string.
2. `(?=^.{0,}[a-zA-Z])` - Assert that a letter also (i.e. *AND*) appears in the string.
3. `[0-9a-zA-Z :,.]{2,}` - "a combination of numbers and letters, and might contain [ :,.]" (assuming the aforementioned assertions)

Similarly, some explanation for the 2nd subpattern (on the right side of the `|`) matching your 2nd set of match criteria:

1. `(?!^\*$)` - Assert that the string is not just `*`.
2. `(?=^[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,})` - Assert that the string contains `*`.
3. `(?!^[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*[0-9.a-zA-Z]{0,}\*)` - Assert that the string does not contain more than one `*`.
4. `[*0-9.a-zA-Z]{2,}` - "a * character + atleast one number OR letter (not necessarily in this order)" (assuming the aforementioned assertions)

*There is probably room to sand & polish the pattern* - especially the lookahead assertions for `*` in the second subpattern I suspect; *but it works and conveys the strategy I employed* of multiple lookahead assertions to constrain each of the two subpatterns to fit your requirements.

Comment: It seems I didnt explain it good enough, I made an edit to the post and posted some actual sample data.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth: I updated my answer to fit your edited question. Once the dust settles a bit (i.e. question mutation has stopped)... :} ..., I will edit it to clean up its split personality.

Answer (score 0):

As you comment below, I think you dose want a full line match, and by saying number and letter, I think it means digits and letters both occurred in the right match.
And by saying "a * character + atleast one number OR letter" I suppose "*" occurs only once in match.

Maybe you could try this one:

```
(^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z :,.]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\*[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\*[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$)
```

It matches:

```
Bf1305020008401 6798ubbii230693
Nettbank til: Troij iudh Betalt: 03.05.13
7509*30.04
*87589
123456*
.*.
test123
123test
```

But won't match any of:

```
&nbsp;
0205
252,25
*
123*345*789
rebound
test
123
```

**Original:**

This should work

```
(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(([A-Za-z]+[ ]*[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[ ]*[A-Za-z]+))[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$)|(^\*[A-Za-z0-9]+$)
```

Comment: It seems I didnt explain it good enough, I made an edit to the post and posted some actual sample data.